# Javascript - time delay between spawns

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-play-games, 2d-games

I have this function ( feel free to use it if you guys need it) that generates monsters for me in random positions outside the play area. After the monster is generated, the monster then follows a way to the character.

But, the problem is that, the monsters are generated all at the same time. What i am trying to do is put some time delay between spawns. Like, 1st monster is generated at the start of the game; second monster i want to be generated after 1 second. Any ideeas how can i achieve this?

I've tried making a time variable that iterates and then spawn an enemy if counter > time. But that dosen't seem to work proprely

```
function init(){

}

function update(dt){

}

function signal(name, value){

    let x1 = 6;
    let x2 = -6;
    let y1 = 20;
    let y2 = 1;
    let cadran =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (+4 - +1)) + +1; 
    if(value){
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){

            if(cadran == 1){
                monsterGenerator(this,x2,x1,y1 ,1);
            }

            if(cadran == 2){
                monsterGenerator(this,x2,x1,y2,2);
            }

            if(cadran == 3){
                monsterGenerator(this,y2,y1,x1,3);
            }


            if(cadran == 4){
                monsterGenerator(this,y2,y1,x2,4);
            }

            cadran++;
            if(cadran==5){
                cadran = 1;
            }
        }
    }

}

function monsterGenerator(ob,min,max,stat,rand) {

    let assetName = ob.attribute('Asset Name');
    let ent = ob.scene().create(assetName);
    if(ent == null) error('Asset "'+assetName+'" does not exist');
    let pos = ob.entity().worldPosition();
    let rot = ob.entity().rotation();
    let scl = ob.entity().scale();
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 

       if(rand==1){
        ent.setPosition(pos.x = random, pos.y =stat , pos.z);
       }
       if(rand==2){
        ent.setPosition(pos.x = random, pos.y =stat , pos.z);
       }
       if(rand==3){
        ent.setPosition(pos.x = stat, pos.y =random , pos.z);
       }
       if(rand==4){
        ent.setPosition(pos.x = stat, pos.y =random , pos.z);
       }

    ent.setRotation(rot.x, rot.y, rot.z);
    ent.setScale(scl.x, scl.y, scl.z);


}
```

Comment: If your game works in 'real time', just use a setIterval() or a setTimeout(). If your game is turn based, just use round X as the point when the monster should appear.

Comment: Just to extend off what @Shilly call setInterval(milliseconds, signal); in your init() function.